# Power BI calculate dates in between 2 or more dates in a single column

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

The first table is dummy data I created which explains about my database, Second bottom table is the result I want to see

[image: The first table is dummy data I created which explains about my database, Second bottom table is the result I want to see]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the most important point is that the DATE&TIME column is set as a date field. Only Date, not Date/Time.

[image: Picture 1]

You can create new column for Date variable or replace existing DATE&TIME column.

[image: Picture 2]

Secondly, you must to create a new measure for Status count.

[image: Picture 3]

Finally, I use to Matrix visualization.

[image: Picture 4]